# CSS Image button styling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something like this[image]

Where the buttons are centered in the middle of the page and separated by 50px

Here is what I did.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="btn btn_tours"><a href="maps.html">Maps</a><span></span></div>
   <div class="btn btn_maps"><a href="dbtest.html">DB Test</a><span></span></div>
   <div class="btn btn_locations"><a href="geolocation.html">Geolocation</a><span></span></div>
   <div class="btn btn_directions"><a href="accel.html">Accelerometer</a><span></span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn { 
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: visible; 
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.btn_directions{ background: url(http://tinyurl.com/5r6a3jy); no-repeat;}
.btn_maps{ background: url(http://tinyurl.com/5r6a3jy); no-repeat; }
.btn_tours{ background: url(http://tinyurl.com/5r6a3jy); no-repeat;}
.btn_locations{ background: url(http://tinyurl.com/5r6a3jy); no-repeat; }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xL9R2/2/)

Comment: "The <center> cannot hold it is too late."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rgmCc/

Comment: How do I scale the image inside the button?

Comment: You can't scale background images (only supported in CSS3)

Comment: You could probably open the images with a "image editor" (like Photoshop or w/e) and than change the size of the images to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle doesn't seem to be loading images.

Wrap your `.btn` in a div. Give it a fixed width and `overflow: hidden;`. Set it to `margin: 0 auto;`. Get rid of the `<center>` tags. Set your `.btn` to `float: left;`.

To horizontally center, an element must have a width and 'auto' on the left and right sides. To set up a grid of elements inside of a div, you'll usually float them.